# kvm: filtering guest traffic with iptables?

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization

I have KVM guests running on a host which is connected via a rfc1918 LAN and a NAT firewall to the internet.

I want the KVM guests to be able to route to machines on the internet, but i want to filter traffic (on the host) so no packets can be sent to rfc1918 addresses.

how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want VMs to be unable to talk to _each other_?

Comment: yes, but I _also_ want them to be unable to talk to the other machines on the LAN.

Comment: generic method: use iptables to forbid other rfc1918 lans as a router, use ebtables to forbid communication between VMs (actually allow only with the "trunk") as a bridge. the right setup puts no IP on the bridge.

Comment: @A.B can you provide a working example?

Comment: i'm running ubuntu 18.04 server (although i'm using ifupdown instead of netplan, for now). i'd like to be compatible with shorewall, if possible, but not necessary. i'd also like to uise libvirt, if possible. also not necessary. nothing else is set in stone. i don't even care about vm-vm isolation, only vm-lan is essential. i have tried combinations of bridging, macvtap, nat, nwfilters. nothing seems to work.

Comment: that would be fantastic!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81786/discussion-between-a-b-and-spongman).

Comment: well my very first comment assumed the VMs were routed behind the host. they are not. and the easy part was vm-vm isolation: it's not important anymore. i just can't do the vm-lan isolation because it has to be done in the lan, and the lan isn't anymore in control of the host (because it's now the real lan, since the VMs are not routed)